# Image upload in firebase storage

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage, firebase-security

I am getting the following error when trying to upload an image in my firebase storage.

Firebase Storage: User does not have permission to access 'images/istockphoto-1071305262-612x612-removebg-preview.png'. (storage/unauthorized)

Below are my db rules:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if
          request.time < timestamp.date(2022, 2, 9);
    }
  }
}
```

Below are the storage rules:

```
rules_version = '2';
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Please share security rules for Cloud Storage. You've shared rules of Firestore. They are both different.

Comment: Initiallly I thought lack of authentication was the issue but upon adding it, the error persisted. Any help will be highly appreciated

Comment: It could be that you are not logged in with any user while making this request? Check if `if true;` works

Comment: Oh i got it. It worked after getting rid of the "if request.auth != null" in the storage rules